# How to raise a note on the html page

Tags: python, html, django

I run my python server using command prompt where the print statements below (if reached) are displayed. How do I display them on the template `login.html`

### Views.py

```
def home(request):
    templatename="login.html"
    if request.method=="POST":
        u=request.POST.get("username")
        p=request.POST.get("password")
        user=authenticate(username=u, password=p)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                print "This User is valid, active and authenticated"
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/welcome/")
            else:
                print("This User is valid but the account has been disabled")
        else:
            print("The Username and Password entered were incorrect")
    else:
        user=None
    return render_to_response(templatename,{'user': user},RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your statement that you want to display on the template `login.html` in a variable ("state" here) like this:

```
def home(request):
    templatename="login.html"
    if request.method=="POST":
        u=request.POST.get("username")
        p=request.POST.get("password")
        user=authenticate(username=u, password=p)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                state="This User is valid, active and authenticated"
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/welcome/")
            else:
                state="This User is valid but the account has been disabled"
        else:
            state="The Username and Password entered were incorrect"
    else:
        user=None
    return render_to_response(templatename,{'user': user,'state':state},RequestContext(request))
```

Pass the state in the dictionary passed to render_to_response().
Access the state in the `login.html` page as {{state}}.
Your work is done.

Answer (score 1):

use instead of

```
print("This User is valid but the account has been disabled")
```

this

```
return HttpResponse("This User is valid but the account has been disabled")
```

here is [Why](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects)

Comment: This displays the message on a new page. But I wanted it to be displayed on my template namely "login.html"

Comment: @h8pathak then you should change the action of your form to ``action=""``